# Table only showing first name but only second name initial

Tags: php, html

I have a table setup on my website to list customers name, purchase date and ticket number although it is only showing the initial of their second name. I would ideally like to have both first name and last name in full. Anyone any ideas? Code snippet below, if you need any other information please ask.

[Click for Image of Table with Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXgj9.png)

```
                                <tr>
                                <td class='firstname'> 
                                    <?php if($order): ?>
                                        <?php  echo $order->get_billing_first_name();?> <?php echo substr($order->get_billing_last_name(), 0, 1); ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </td> 
                                <td class="date"><?php echo date_i18n( 'F jS', strtotime( $history_value->date )); ?></td>
                                <td class='ticket_number'><?php echo apply_filters( 'ticket_number_display_html' ,$history_value->ticket_number, $product_data);?></td> 
                            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo substr($order->get_billing_last_name(), 0, 1); ?
```

Its because you are parsing only one letter :) Try just

```
<?php echo $order->get_billing_last_name(); ?>
```

What substr does:

```
<?php
substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"
substr("abcdef", -2);    // returns "ef" 
substr("abcdef", -3, 1); // returns "d"
?>
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense! I have just tried the refined code and still does not seem to make a difference to the second name. Strange!

Comment: Of course, once I am home I will get that over to you.